# MySQL: date format changed when retrieving it by node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have made a table with personal information with DOB as "Date" type. When I select the entire table in the terminal, it shows the correct format(YYYY-MM-DD). However, when I created an connection through node.js and output to the console, it was printed as a JSON object where the DOB now has hh-mm-ss behind the actual date?

For example one of my column has DOB as "1996-03-06". However, when it is passed to the node.js server and printe to the console log, it became "1996-03-0605:00:00.000Z"

What is more strange is that when I send this information to Ajax to print to the web, the output is actually something like this: Wed Mar 06 1996 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST), which is different from both the actual data and the data that was shown in the console

Comment: It looks like maybe Node converted the dates to timestamps set to midnight.  Nothing wrong with this, just display as much information as you want.

Comment: However, when I send this piece of information thru Ajax and print to the web, the output becomes: Wed Mar 06 1996 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST),which is different from both the actual data and the data that was shown in the console. how do I make it so that I just show YYYY-MM-DD?

Comment: can you upload that part of code you are sending using node.js?

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue my self.
There is a connection param called **dateStrings** that defaults to false;
This switched it back to traditional behavior.

```js
const conn = await mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.DBHOST,
    user: process.env.DBUSER,
    password: process.env.DBPASS,
    port: process.env.DBPORT,
    database: process.env.DATABASE,
    dateStrings: true // <--- fix
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just print or send in ajax whatever you need from the `Date` object

```
console.log(DOB.toISOString().slice(0,10))
```